# Browser back button not forwarding to the previous page if posts have been made

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The scenario is the following:

In an ASP.NET Webforms application,the main page loads (e.g. **Home**). Then i click on a link and get forwarded  to another page of the solution (e.g. **Customers**). Now, if i do 2 searches on the page (there's a search button that queries the DB and updates a grid), and click brower's back button, instead of being forwarded back to the Home page, i stay on the Customers page. I have to click the back button 2 more times (as many as the posts made) in order to get forwarded properly to the Home page.

Anyone knows why this works like that or what can i do to make the browser's back button forward me to the previous page no matter how many posts i made on the current page?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an .aspx page between your home page and your about page. It probably serves a the purpose of checking for errors or validating information from the first page. When you click the back button from the about page, it navigates back to the inbetween page which contains the code to send it back to the about page. The inbetween page is usually processed so fast that you only see a brief flash of it in the address bar.

The best solution would be a link to navigate back to the home page, if you are not the author, I don't think there is much that you can do :P.

Comment: There's no .aspx page in between as this page was made from scratch. I edited the original post though to clarify that actually it needs POSTS for the "bug" to occur, just hitting f5 for refresh does not cause this issue and you can go to the previous page with just 1 click no matter how many times you f5'd.